# Update in first php call not working in firefox.. but works in chrome and explorer

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have an HTML page that populates data using PHP - testcommand.php.
On a button press the page should update a record in MySQL- updmeal_order.php, and then call a new webpage - add-meals.php.

This works in chrome and explorer but in firefox, it does not.  In firefox the button fires and calls the new webpage but does not do the update.
If I remove the calling of the new webpage, the update does work.

Thanks in advance
Osie

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

    var xparam = getUrlParameter('ref');    

    $("body").delegate("#addmeals", "click", function(event){

// update table in mysql    
        event.preventDefault();    
        var mo_desc = document.getElementById('mo_desc').value;     
        var bh_no   = document.getElementById('bh_no').value;               
            var updparam  = bh_no+mo_desc;
    //alert (xparam);
                var url = "../js/updmeal_order.php";
    //            var dataString = $(this).serialize().replace(/\'/g,'\\\'');           
                // POST values in the background the the script URL
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: url,
                     data: ({xparam: updparam}),
                    success: function (data)
                    {
    //var myJSON = JSON.stringify(data);                    
    //alert (myJSON);
                    }
                });


// call a new webpage    
            var path = '../command/add-meals.php?ref='+bh_no;    
        window.location.href=path;        
        $.ajax({
             url: path, 
             type: "POST",
    //       data: ({mo_desc: mo_desc}),
             success: function()
                 {
    //       var arraydata = $.parseJSON(data);          
    //        $("#command").html(arraydata[0]); 
             }
        });  
    /*
    */

    });


// display data in main htm page    
        $.ajax({
             url: '../command/testcommand.php', 
             type: "POST",
             data: ({xparam: xparam}),
             success: function(data){
             var arraydata = $.parseJSON(data);          
              $("#command").html(arraydata[0]); 
             }
        });  






    });
```

Comment: btw: I changed the calling form to a simple htm form but still get the error, so the error is not in add-meals.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I had was that pressing the back button(from add-meals.php) on firefox seems to rollback the mysql update, whereas on chrome/explorer it is commited... bizarre?

Calling the page first and then the update seems to have solved this